# CSS Animation on SVG Element on iOS Safari 11 Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, svg, css-animations

I have a simple SVG that animates when it comes into viewport (via added class in Javascript). It's a simple bar chart that is supposed to animate the height of 2 rect elements.

It works fine everywhere except iPad Safari 11.1.2 (and maybe below)

When I remove the animation the SVG displays fine. The class is being added via javascript and webkit vendor prefixes are added for browser support.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @keyframes draw {
      from {
        height: 0;
      }
      to {
        height: 110px;
      }
    }

    @keyframes drawBig {
      from {
        height: 0;
      }
      to {
        height: 360px;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes draw {
        from {
            height: 0;
        }
        to {
            height: 110px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes drawBig {
      from {
        height: 0;
      }
      to {
        height: 360px;
      }
    }

    .animate-bar {
      animation: draw 1s linear forwards;
      animation-play-state: paused;
      -webkit-animation: draw 1s linear forwards;
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    .animate-bar.bar-large {
        animation-name: drawBig;
        -webkit-animation-name: drawBig;
    }
    .play .animate-bar {
        animation-play-state: running;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    }
</style>

<svg id="diagram" viewBox="0 0 290 472" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="svg" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="left">
            <rect class="animate-bar" x="0" y="283" width="132" height="107" rx="3" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-676)">
            </rect>
            <text font-weight="bold">
                <tspan x="47.384" y="263">1129</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
        <g id="right" transform="translate(152,0)">
            <rect class="animate-bar bar-large" fill="#EEE6E2" x="0" y="33" width="132" height="360" rx="3" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-426)">
            </rect>
            <text font-weight="bold">
                <tspan x="36.56" y="17">4000</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The CSS is just manipulating the height of the bars in the animation (which is paused until the class is added).

On iOS 11 though the bars just never animate so both heights appear to be 0 and you can't see either.

When I look in dev tools I can see the `<rect>` elements flashing in the DOM indicating something is happening to them (even though the only thing that should manipulate them is the CSS animation) but they are flashing very fast so I can't see what.

I'm at a loss of what else to try.

Here is a fiddle of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/peuzdL2n/7/

Works in everything except iOS Safari 11 and below as far as I can see

Comment: Try animating `transform: translateY(110px);` instead of height

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work